# Skydiving or paragliding options in Europe

Tags: europe, adventure, amsterdam, parachutes-skydiving

I am looking for options to have skydiving or paragliding near Amsterdam. I know both (skydiving and paragliding) are very different but I want to have adventurous sky view. Near Amsterdam doesn't mean in Netherlands or nearby country but any good location preferably closer to Amsterdam. Good location means:

- Cheaper in terms of money
- Distance from Amsterdam
- View
- Safety
- Height etc.

I found some sky diving options in Texel, Netherlands which is too costly for me (Euro 350/- Approx.) I want to plan holiday for 2 weeks and good answer can really help me in choosing my holiday destination.

Answer (score 2):

Near Amsterdam, paragliding is not an option, since you need mountains for it, as far as I know.

In terms of money, you could consider the [skydiving centre in Teuge](http://www.paracentrumteuge.nl/Home.aspx). I am assuming you are not an experienced skydiver. Than you can jump outside of the weekends/public holidays for [175 euros](http://www.paracentrumteuge.nl/Tandemspringen/Prijzen.aspx).

In terms of your other requirements. Teuge is closer to Amsterdam than Texel, slightly more than an hour by car. Teuge is located very close to the [Veluwe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veluwe), which is one of the largest natural landscapes in the Netherlands. According to the website you will jump from 3km height. I can't judge the safety, but I don't think this is something to worry about in the Netherlands.

Comment: Paragliding does not require mountains people paraglide from Dunstable Downs 35 miles north of London for example without them.https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mizDXsmqQmU  It may be paragliding is better in mountains but anywhere a thermal updraft can be generated by geography will work.

Comment: People do paragliding along the Dutch beaches, but only when the weather is favorable. And that is mostly in the summer.