# Adventure sports in Germany

Tags: germany, adventure, parachutes-skydiving

We are going to a backpack trip across western Europe and we want to give our adrenaline gland the rush of life time.

So, please suggest some places (and nearby cities) where we can do stuff like sky diving, para gliding diving in Germany

There has been a similar question [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19391/skydiving-or-paragliding-options-in-europe?rq=1) and [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64728/sky-diving-and-other-adventure-sport-in-western-europe) but the answers did not help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sky diving and other adventure sport in Western Europe](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64728/sky-diving-and-other-adventure-sport-in-western-europe)

Comment: @GayotFow that possible duplicate is on-hold and unanswered, the OP has been asked to narrow down which they have done in this question.

Comment: Doing a web search for sky diving in Germany, I see at least 6 different cities/places for outdoor, several additional for tandem outdoor, and then there are at least 5 indoor sky diving places, and I haven't even started on the para gliding. How is this still not too broad? What the user is asking for is a recommendation of a place, which we (I) will not do. Just because I had a great time at a place, doesn't mean it's what the user will have, or want, and conversely, just because I had a horrible time, the user might not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially either a request for the 'best' which is unanswerable, or a "list" of businesses and places, which is too broad (in this case).

Comment: @mts, sorry, it's an opinion poll, as was the previous one. I'll have to let my close vote ride.

Comment: @CGCampbell & Gayot fair points, go ahead!

Comment: Please edit the question to make it on-topic for the site. As it stands it's gathering close votes.

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point might be [Jochen Schweizer](http://www.jochen-schweizer.de/) (website in German, no affiliation). They sell vouchers for experiences which includes bungee jumping, tandem jumps, ice-climbing and a lot more.

Have a look at the website (with a translation tool). On the left there is a search bar where you can filter for Price, target group ("Für alle"), category and location ("Ort"). Filter for Adventure&Sports ("Abenteuer & Sport"), some of that might be adventurous enough for your liking (I doubt you were looking for a golf experience).

If I understand their business model correctly they sell a voucher for an experience and then you have to agree on a date with the local guide/organizer (which could be variable also in function of weather conditions, you can't do outdoor ice climbing in August), so make sure this fits your plans before you book. At least it can serve you as an inspiration for further internet search.